# How to position rotated text to the right of image

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I am trying to position a vertical (rotated) copyright notice to the right of an image using css. I can almost get it working, but it still positions the text relative to the page, which is not a workable option (it must position relative to the picture or containing div). I'd prefer to use a pure css solution, but if that isn't possible, I'd also welcome JQuery solutions.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/s5zYj/4/

**Edit:** I should have specified that I'm looking for a *general* solution, which works for any reasonable length name (not just Mickey Mouse).

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Some text <br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
<div>
    <img class="caption" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/300/cats/"/>
        <span class="image-copyright"><small>&copy; Mickey Mouse</small></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-copyright {
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%; /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    color: gray;
    right: 58px;
}
```

**Desired result**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this css

```
.image-copyright {
position: absolute;

transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform-origin:100% 100%;
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
-ms-transform-origin:100% 100%; /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
z-index: 100;
color: gray;
right: -20px; /*edited*/
top:-18px;
}

#container {
position:relative;
background:yellow;
display:inline-block;
}
```

and I gave the parent div for the img, an id of "container".

Comment: This seems to be working (though I had to add `top:-18px;` to `image-copyright`): http://jsfiddle.net/s5zYj/11/. Unless testing breaks it, I think this is the right answer.

Comment: I think transform-origin is safe for use now: http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS3%202D%20Transforms

Answer (score 1):

I was able to complete this using `inline-block`, `vertical-align:top` and a negative `margin-left`

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5zYj/6/) with it working. I'm not a fan of using the `margin-left: -75px` but using the `transform:rotate` property unfortunately leaves some extra whitespace to the left that needs to be accounted for.

Comment: Thanks Zack; as I mentioned in my comment to Ryan Brewer, this is good for the given example, but I'd like something more general if possible.

Answer (score 1):

No need to position absolutely just use `float:left` and `display:inline-block` then a negative margin to the image.

HTML:

```
<div><p>Some text</p>
    <img class="caption" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/300/cats/" />
    <div class="image-copyright"><small>&copy; Mickey Mouse</small></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-copyright {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    color: gray;
    margin-left:-75px;
}
.caption {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/s5zYj/9/)

Comment: This works well for the given caption, but I'm looking for a general solution that will work for any text. If I use, say "Mickey Mouse the Magnificent" in your demo, the alignment goes out again.

Comment: If you use a longer line of text just increase the negative `margin-left` property on the image: http://jsfiddle.net/brewersomething/s5zYj/10/

Comment: Granted the above solution is not dynamic so if you have multiple images with multiple captions you would have to set the `margin-left` each time. If I have time I'll try to work out a more dynamic solution that doesn't use any Javascript. It would be easy with Javascript! :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why people are so anti-absolute positioning. Often it's the most reliable solution if you understand how it works:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/kgrote/pen/yBAtF)

Let's assume the `<div>` wrapping your image and caption has the class of `.picture`:

```
.picture {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.picture .image-copyright {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
transform-origin: 80% 400%;
<!--for all browsers-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Y'all are crazy do you not know about `writing-mode: vertical-rl`?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  text-align: right;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekeanu.com/400/300" alt="Your Image">
  <h3>Heading</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Y'all are crazy do you not know about `writing-mode: vertical-rl`?

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

h3 {
  text-align: right;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placekeanu.com/400/300" alt="Your Image">
  <h3>Heading</h3>
</div>
```